# Is 15 year 2.5% rate through credit union a good option

Tags: refinance

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121358/is-it-a-good-time-for-refinance-why-rates-are-different-in-wellsfargo-website)

I have $180k principle remaining as of today with 30-year / 3.75% interest rate. I am able to lock 15 year 2.5% rate. I have been paying extra $X amount principle every month and by refinancing I basically pay the same amount including extra principle but paying off in 15 year. This is through a credit union and not a bank.

I am wondering is it a good rate and rates cannot get lower than that or I should wait?

Comment: How much will it cost you to refi, and is there any chance you would sell the property in the near future?

Comment: It cost $1500 to refinance and no I'm no I'm not planning on selling the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can afford the payment on the 15-year rate, then it's most likely worth refinancing. The rule of thumb is that you must drop your rate by 1% to have a decent payback time for the closing costs.

The main calculation is to look at the amount of *interest* paid in the first month, compare that to how much interest you're paying now, and divide the total closing costs by that difference. That gives you the break-even period in months, meaning that's how many months will pass before you've made up the closing costs in interest savings.

Make sure that the quoted rate does not include any points (prepaid interest) added to lower the rate. They will increase your upfront costs and lengthen the payback period.

As to whether rates will go down - no one knows for sure.